# SQL query structure not returning correct results

Tags: sql

i have the following query

```
SELECT eventID, description, title, event_start, event_end, userID
FROM SIS_EVENT 
WHERE userID=1 OR (userID=0) AND
      event_start >=01/01/2017 AND event_end <=10/10/2017
```

This will work but only selects the record with the userID of 1 and will not return any with a userID of 0

I feel is is like to the structure of my SQL but im not sure what im doing wrong
Any help is appreciated

Below is the SQL in code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT eventID, description, title, 
event_start, event_end, userID FROM SIS_EVENT WHERE userID IN (0, @user_id) 
AND event_start >= '@start' AND event_end <= '@end' ", con); 

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", HttpContext.Current.Session["userid"]);
```

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you are using (Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, whatever). Your SQL is invalid (and doesn't even match the code below). `01/01/2017` means 1 divided by 1 divided by 2017. `'01/01/2017'` would be better, but depends on database settings to have the DBMS interpret the string correctly. The logical error is here: `userID=1 OR (userID=0 AND ...)` as `AND` has precedence over `OR`. Use parentheses to solve this: `WHERE (userID=1 OR userID=0) AND ...`. Depending on the DBMS and data type you might still have problems with a possible time part in `event_start` and `event_end`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your intention, you should be writing the query like this:

```
SELECT eventID, description, title, event_start, event_end, userID
FROM SIS_EVENT 
WHERE userID IN (0, 1) AND
      event_start >= '2017-01-01' AND
      event_end <= '2017-10-10';
```

Notes:

- Date constants should be in single quotes.
- You should use ISO-standard syntax for dates (note:  in some databases you may need to precede the string with `date`).
- Use `IN` for multiple comparisons.

Comment: I used in in the query builder in my little admin and it worked, once moved into my code, it continues to only retrieve the events like to the user_id but not any which have a userID of 0, what would be wrong here.  I have add the code above

Comment: @JamesCrozier . . . `AddWithValue()` can have problems.  Add the parameters with the correct types -- and when you do, you won't need quotes around the dates.

Comment: I have removed the quotes and dates work okay, but the issue is its only pulling data linked to AddwithValue() of userID, and not the hardcoded userID=0 that i also need.

Comment: Don't use `AddwithValue()` . . . convert the value to an `int` in the application and add the value that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should trying using brackets between two logical comparision.

Comment: there is not double equal sign for comparison in SQL. neither is the use of brackets

Comment: Thanks for informing me @Josue Martinez

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parenthesis to delimit your conditions.
This will work:

```
SELECT eventID, description, title, event_start, event_end, userID FROM SIS_EVENT WHERE (userID=1 OR userID=0) AND event_start >=01/01/2017 AND event_end <=10/10/2017
```

Or as the condition is for the same column you could use "IN":

```
SELECT eventID, description, title, event_start, event_end, userID FROM SIS_EVENT WHERE (userID=1 OR userID=0) AND event_start >= 01/01/2017 AND event_end <= 10/10/2017;
```

Answer (score 0):

first your problem was where you put the or condition that turned the condition 
into -> is userId equal 1 or the rest
and about the datetime the comparison needed some converting here is my code improvement:

```
 SELECT eventID, description, title, event_start, event_end, userID
        FROM SIS_EVENT 
        WHERE userID IN (0, 1) AND
             Convert(DateTime, event_start) >=Convert(DateTime,'2017-01-01',106) AND
             Convert(DateTime, event_end) <=Convert(DateTime,'2017-10-10',106);
```